# How to replace a color in PDF to another color?

Tags: php, pdf, colors

I have a multiple PDF's with multiple pages (20 to 60 pages) with colored 'blocks'.
I want to replace light-red with dark-red as in #ff6060 to #ff0000;
Only in 'fields', not even text or images.

Now, i can use Infix to manually open one PDF and change 1 color at a time. This works, but is a lot of work.
I want to do this in PHP, so I can upload a PDF in a simple form, swap the colors from light-red/light-green to dark-red/dark-green and automatily download a changed/altered PDF.

There are tons of PDF-sdk's and frameworks, but non of this can swap/change/alter/update colors.

How to do this?

I dont have any code yet, I am mostly seeking for a right way/software.

Comment: You're talking about changing colours - have you considered drawing over or is this not an option for some reason?

Comment: If all these blocks are placed at specific coordinates (like at the top-right corner), you may draw over as kelkka suggests. If not, you may convert your PDF to images, then find all light-red pixels, replace them to dark-red, and convert to PDF again. PDF conversion can be done via imagick (https://imagemagick.org/index.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php), finding colors via `imagecolorat()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php). Not an ideal solution, but should be technically possible

Comment: Having worked with PDF a lot I can tell you that this is going to be pretty complicated, even though it seems like a simple find-and-replace should do it. The PDF format stores things at byte offsets, so a loss or gain of a character can mess a lot up. And even though RGB is bound to 256 possibilities which can always be expressed as two hex chars, in PDF they are stored as variable integer strings from 0 through 255. If you can do Java or .Net I'd push you towards iText/iTextSharp which _might_ be able to do this, but I can't promise that 100%.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely possible, and arguably easy to do with the right SDK. However, this question is not appropriate for StackOverflow, https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Instead you should ask here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks all for the help, converting to img and change that and put them all in a new PDF is probaly the best and only working solution. Thanks for giving directory.

Ryan: I have software to do this (Infix) But want to do it wat easier with php.